# Lua - read a csv file, update some values (calculations) and write new file

Tags: csv, lua, energy

I’ve been writing values to a text/csv file, but as certain information has now changed, I need to update the file to reflect the new values/calculations.

The text/csv file is a report on energy used, sample below, and it’s the `KwH Unit Cost` and `Cost` (which is calculated from the `KWH Used` * `KwH Unit Cost`) that both need updating.

```
Date Time Run,  Start Epoc,  End Epoc, KwH Start, KwH End, KwH Used, KwH Unit Cost, Cost Spent
2022-12-11 13:12:53, 1670763866, 1670764373, 7841.1690, 7841.2920, 0.12, 0.3506, 0.04, 
2022-12-11 23:59:00, 1670764373, 1670803140, 7841.2920, 7853.5480, 12.26, 0.3506, 4.3,
```

I’m able to parse the csv/text file to a table, but I’m unable to work out how to extract update the unit cost from `0.3506` to `0.3877` and recalculate the `Cost` based on that new rate.

My Lua code is below, which shows the cost values. That’s as far as I’m able to go ..

```
local CSV = [[Date Time Run,  Start Epoc,  End Epoc, KwH Start, KwH End, KwH Used, KwH Unit Cost, Cost Spent
2022-12-11 13:12:53, 1670763866, 1670764373, 7841.1690, 7841.2920, 0.12, 0.3506, 0.04, 
2022-12-11 23:59:00, 1670764373, 1670803140, 7841.2920, 7853.5480, 12.26, 0.3506, 4.3, 
2022-12-12 23:59:00, 1670803140, 1670889540, 7853.5480, 7887.0740, 33.53, 0.3506, 11.76, 
2022-12-13 23:59:00, 1670889540, 1670975940, 7887.0740, 7917.4370, 30.36, 0.3506, 10.64, ]]

local function tprint (tbl, indent)
  if not indent then indent = 0 end
  for k, v in pairs(tbl) do
    formatting = string.rep("  ", indent) .. k .. ": "
    if type(v) == "table" then
      print(formatting)
      tprint(v, indent+1)
    elseif type(v) == 'boolean' then
      print(formatting .. tostring(v))      
    else
      print(formatting .. v)
    end
  end
end

local linePattern = "[^\r\n]+"
local csWordPattern = "[^,]+"

local function parseCsv(csv)
    local rows = {}
    for line in string.gmatch(csv, linePattern) do
        local row = {}
        for word in string.gmatch(line,csWordPattern) do
            table.insert(row, word)
        end
        table.insert(rows, row)
    end

    return rows
end

local CSV_Table = parseCsv(CSV)
print(tprint(CSV_Table))

for k,v in pairs(CSV_Table) do
    --print (k,v)
    for k1,v1 in pairs(v) do 
        --print (k1,v1)
        if k1 == 8 then 
            print(v1)
        end
    end
end
```

Any/all help greatly appreciated..

Comment: I think i'm missing the problem here. What stops you from replacing the exact string, update the cost (e.g. `0.3877 * v[6]`), convert back to a string using `tostring`, then dump the file back using `table.concat(v, ", ")` or similar?

Comment: Hi @Luke100000 , thanks for responding, what you described sounds exactly like what I’m struggling to work out how to do. How do I generate those new rows within the table with  those two updated/new values ?

Comment: you can collect the results of those table.concats described earlier in a new table, then table.concat(t, "\n") this into your final file. That means, you do not need the inner loop, and you need to skip the first row, e.g. `k ~= 1` since the header should not get modified.

Comment: Thanks @Luke100000, I think I follow the final table.concat part, it’s the updating of v[7] and v[8] in each row I’m struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get my code to work, here’s what I used in the end..

```
local CSV = [[Date Time Run,  Start Epoc,  End Epoc, KwH Start, KwH End, KwH Used, KwH Unit Cost, Cost Spent
2022-12-11 13:12:53, 1670763866, 1670764373, 7841.1690, 7841.2920, 0.12, 0.3506, 0.04, 
2022-12-11 23:59:00, 1670764373, 1670803140, 7841.2920, 7853.5480, 12.26, 0.3506, 4.3, 
2022-12-12 23:59:00, 1670803140, 1670889540, 7853.5480, 7887.0740, 33.53, 0.3506, 11.76, 
2022-12-13 23:59:00, 1670889540, 1670975940, 7887.0740, 7917.4370, 30.36, 0.3506, 10.64, ]]

local linePattern = "[^\r\n]+"
local csWordPattern = "[^,]+"

local function parseCsv(csv)
    local rows = {}
    for line in string.gmatch(csv, linePattern) do
        local row = {}
        for word in string.gmatch(line,csWordPattern) do
            table.insert(row, word)
        end
        table.insert(rows, row)
    end
    return rows
end

local data = parseCsv(CSV)
local newarr = {}
for i,v in pairs(data) do
    local rate = 0.386
    local usage = tonumber(v[6])
    if type(usage ) == "number" then
        local cost = (usage * rate)
        table.insert(newarr, {v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4], v[5], v[5], v[6], rate, cost})
    else
        table.insert(newarr, {v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4], v[5], v[5], v[6], v[7], v[8]})
    end
end

for k, v in pairs(newarr) do
    print(table.concat(v,", ")) 
end
```